# "On Numbers and Games" or "Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays"?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm really interested in John Conway's work on games and I want to spend my winter reading something of his but I'm not sure between "On Numbers and Games" or "Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays", since they seem pretty similar. What are the differences between the books and which would you recommend?

Comment: Read them simultaneously and give up on one if it seems boring.

Comment: I read those two simultaneously, but I would recommend Lessons in Play as a starter book over either of those. It's more accessible to an undergrad and generally clearer about theorems and proofs, for the most part. After that, if you want to read heavier/broader theory, Combinatorial Game Theory by Siegel would be a good option (covering essentially all of the theorems from ONAG and WW), but it doesn't have too many examples, being a graduate textbook.

Answer (score 3):

Winning Ways is a much longer work and has a lot more examples of applying the theory to actual games.  It has some proofs of results, but the nitty-gritty foundational details of the theory are left out.  For those, you have to read "On Numbers and Games" (ONAG).

ONAG is much more condensed in terms of applying the theory to actual games (of course there are still many examples there), but it develops the theory from scratch. It also has more results of theoretical interest like the algebraic structure of the surreal numbers, and the structure of infinite and infinitesimal games.

Personally, I discovered Winning Ways first, and found the theory fascinating but difficult for me to make rigorous on my own.  Then later I discovered ONAG, and I think having first read WW (at least the first 2 volumes*) made ONAG easier to read.

*Here I am talking about the latest printing of WW; in the original, the first two volumes were combined into one.

Comment: So it seems like reading them together sounds like a good idea. ONAG gives me theory and rigour and Winning Ways applications, examples and intuition?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable thing to do.